# How to authenticate IMAP accounts programmatically?

Tags: android, account

In my android application I need to authenticate several types of accounts.Google accounts are easy to authenticate .But I am Fail in **IMAP/POP3** accounts.
Is there is any methode to  authenticate **IMAP/POP3** accounts by programming?

Comment: What do you mean with "authenticate"? getting the credentials or opening a connection and authenticate against the server using the credentials?

Comment: May be you should post the code (edit your question) you are using for "Google authentication" then we understand better what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I am trying to add IMAP account by programming.

Comment: @Dhaneesh, Did you manage to find a solution for this? I am trying to achieve the same in my project..

Comment: @ambit still I facing that problem...